# How can I make Watson assistant repeat the last response?

Tags: spring-el, watson-assistant

I would like to have my watson assistant repeat the response that was given before.

I have an Intent that matches e.g. "Can you please repeat that?".
Then if that Intent is matched, the answer should be the same that was given before.

Is there a way to archieve that? 
How can I access the answer from before in the [expression language](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-evaluation-syntax)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this within Watson Assistant itself. The most straightforward way would be to configure each dialog node to store the value of `output.generic.text` in a context variable, and then you could use that variable as needed. But if you have many dialog nodes, that could be a tedious task and pose some maintenance headaches.

Another approach would be to try to tackle this at the application layer, which would have some advantages. If your application could catch requests to repeat, then you could handle those (caching the previous turn's dialog response and just repeating it upon request). The advantage to this approach is that by not handling a repetition request within Watson Assistant itself, you won't be interfering with the current session state -- this could be especially useful if the user was in the middle of providing prompted information for a slot, for instance. You wouldn't need to manage this as a digression or anything like that.

But if you aren't able to handle this at the application layer, there aren't any really great options. I think it would be great if IBM considered adding a global response repeat function at the Assistant level (would be especially great for Voice Agent / Voice Gateway applications).